# VC++ DLL (Non MFC): What are the different reliable ways to log information

Tags: visual-c++, logging, trace

I am working on a VC++ DLL that uses [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) (Simplified Wrapper and Interface Generator) for C#. The DLL does not use ATL or MFC, it is set to use only the Standard Windows Libraries. Now because of some memory issues, I want to output formatted messages from functions to a log file. What are the different way to do that? Is there a pre-existing trace class that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know just 3 different ways to do it:

1. Use one of the [existing log libraries for C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696321/best-logging-framework-for-native-c). This is the most flexible approach since you can profit from many nice features like formatting, different appenders etc
2. Use [OutputDebugString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. This function sends message to the debugger, but does not put it to any file by default.
3. Implement your own simple logger

I hope this helps.